# Contextual binding in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection, laravel-6

Following the Laravel [document](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/container#contextual-binding), I want to bind an implementation `TransferToInventory` that implements the interface `Processable` to a specific class (`Handler`).

**Processable interface**

```php
interface Processable
{
    public function process(array $data);
}
```

**TransferToInventory class**

```php
class TransferToInventory implements Processable
{
    public function process(array $data): void
    {
        dd($data);
    }
}
```

**Handler**

```php
class Handler
{
    protected $data;
    protected $processor;

    /**
     * This is incoming JSON payload, already decoded to an array
     *   - var_dump($data);
     *
     * Raw JSON payload from SQS, if necessary
     *   - var_dump($job->getRawBody());
     *
     * @param  Job   $job
     * @param  array $data
     */
    public function handle(Job $job, array $data)
    {
        resolve(Processorable::class)->process($data);
    }
}
```

I put dependencies binding in the AppServiceProvider.

```php
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->when(Handler::class)
            ->needs(Processable::class)
            ->give(function () {
                return new TransferToInventory;
            });
    }

    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

But I always got the following error.

> local.ERROR: Target [App\Services\Contract\Processable] is not
>   instantiable.

Comment: php artisan clear-compiled  + php artisan optimize + php artisan config:cache ?

Comment: maybe you can use `$this->app->bind(Processable::class, function() use ($model){return new TransferToInventory;}); `

Comment: what is this `Handler` class? what calls this? and i will assume all those class references in the `AppServiceProvider` are aliased?

Answer (score 1):

What ever this `Handler` class is would need to be resolved from the container and would need to have a type-hinting dependency in its constructor for this interface for the contextual binding to work.

Answer (score 0):

As lagbox suggested, it worked for me as below:

```
class Handler
{
    protected $data;
    protected $processor;

    public function __construct(Processable $processor)
    {
        $this->processor = $processor;
    }

    public function handle(Job $job, array $data)
    {
        $this->processor->process($data);
    }
    
}
```